# How to display custom icons for files in JFileChooser?

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

How to display custom icons for files in `JFileChooser`? Well i neither want the default system icon for the files nor the default icon that comes with `JFileChooser`. I want my own icon.

I want to set the icon for a file by it's extension. How could i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can make use of the `Hashtable` which contains the extension as `String` type and an `ImageIcon`

`Hashtable` is in `java.util` package

`FileView` is in `javax.swing.filechooser` package

```
// Create a hashtable for String,ImageIcon
Hashtable<String,ImageIcon> table=new Hashtable<>();

    // Add extensions and icons
    table.put(".txt",new ImageIcon("txtfile.png"));
    table.put(".doc",new ImageIcon("docfile.png"));
    table.put(".ppt",new ImageIcon("pptfile.png"));
    table.put(".lnk",new ImageIcon("link.png"));
    table.put(".png",new ImageIcon("image.png"));
    table.put(".gif",new ImageIcon("image.png"));
    table.put(".jpeg",new ImageIcon("image.png"));
    table.put(".jpg",new ImageIcon("image.png"));
```

In the class `MyFileView`

```
class MyFileView extends FileView
{
Hashtable<String,ImageIcon> table;
ImageIcon dirIcon;

    public MyFileView(Hashtable<String,ImageIcon> table,ImageIcon dirIcon)
    {
        this.table=table;
        this.dirIcon=dirIcon;
    }

    public Icon getIcon(File f)
    {
    // Do display custom icons

        // If dir
        if(f.isDirectory()) 
        {
            if(dirIcon!=null) return dirIcon;
        return new ImageIcon("myfoldericon.png");
        }

        // Get the name
        String name=f.getName();
        int idx=name.lastIndexOf(".");

        if(idx>-1)
        {
        String ext=name.substring(idx);
            if(table.containsKey(ext))
        return table.get(ext);
        }

    // For other files
    return new ImageIcon("myownfileicon.png");
    }
}
```

And the code to use this,

```
MyFileView m=new MyFileView(table,new ImageIcon("diricon.png"));
JFileChooser jf=new JFileChooser();
jf.setFileView(m);
jf.showOpenDialog(this);
```

If we don't want by extension or if we want to set a custom icon for hard drive, my computer then we can make use of the UI defaults.